# Dont we have option for dynamic content inside mat-tooltip?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to angular material components, we are using mat-tooltip to show the tooltip content on all elements.

It is showing up properly when we are using the tooltip with static content like below.

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="Back" matTooltip="Go to reports using this column"></mat-icon>
```

Now, I need mat-tooltip to show dynamic content, not just plain text.

```
<div #myTootltipContent>
 <span>tooltip text</span>
 <span>tootlip description</span>
</div>
```

I need this `div` to be shown on hover of another element. Is it possible with mat-tooltip? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What you're looking for is named a `popover` and material simply doesn't have that built in. there are many libraries that do though, [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples) for example is one of them. google for more.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is not available out of the box in MatToolTip but you can make use of Angular CDK to implement a custom tooltip by using `OverlayModule` of cdk. I have recently implemented a custom tooltip directive which shows the custom tooltip. Here is the working stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7zevt?file=app%2Ftool-tip-renderer.directive.ts

First, have a component which will be hosted in Overlay like this -

```
/**
 * This component will be used to show custom tooltip
 * 
 * This component will be rendered using OverlayModule of angular material
 * This component will be rendered by the directive on an Overlay
 * 
 * CONSUMER will not be using this component directly
 * This component will be hosted in an overlay by ToolTipRenderer directive
 * This component exposes two properties. These two properties will be filled by ToolTipRenderer directive
 * 1. text - This is a simple string which is to be shown in the tooltip; This will be injected in the ToolTipRenderer directive
 *    by the consumer
 * 2. contentTemplate - This gives finer control on the content to be shown in the tooltip
 * 
 * NOTE - ONLY one should be specified; If BOTH are specified then "template" will be rendered and "text" will be ignored
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-tool-tip',
  templateUrl: './custom-tool-tip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-tool-tip.component.css']
})
export class CustomToolTipComponent implements OnInit {

  /**
   * This is simple text which is to be shown in the tooltip
   */
  @Input() text: string;

  /**
   * This provides finer control on the content to be visible on the tooltip
   * This template will be injected in ToolTipRenderer directive in the consumer template
   * <ng-template #template>
   *  content.....
   * </ng-template>
   */
  @Input() contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now have a directive which will use an overlay to render the above component -

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customToolTip]'
})
export class ToolTipRendererDirective {

   /**
   * This will be used to show tooltip or not
   * This can be used to show the tooltip conditionally
   */
  @Input() showToolTip: boolean = true;

  //If this is specified then the specified text will be shown in the tooltip
  @Input(`customToolTip`) text: string;

  //If this is specified then specified template will be rendered in the tooltip
  @Input() contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  private _overlayRef: OverlayRef;

  constructor(private _overlay: Overlay,
              private _overlayPositionBuilder: OverlayPositionBuilder,
              private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  /**
   * Init life cycle event handler
   */
  ngOnInit() {

    if (!this.showToolTip) {
      return;
    }

    //you can take the position as an input to adjust the position
    //, for now, it will show at the bottom always; but you can adjust your code
      as per your need
    const positionStrategy = this._overlayPositionBuilder
                                 .flexibleConnectedTo(this._elementRef)
                                 .withPositions([{
                                                    originX: 'center',
                                                    originY: 'bottom',
                                                    overlayX: 'center',
                                                    overlayY: 'top',
                                                    offsetY: 5,
                                                }]);

    this._overlayRef = this._overlay.create({ positionStrategy});

  }

  /**
   * This method will be called whenever the mouse enters in the Host element
   * i.e. where this directive is applied
   * This method will show the tooltip by instantiating the CustomToolTipComponent and attaching to the overlay
   */
  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  show() {

    //attach the component if it has not already attached to the overlay
    if (this._overlayRef && !this._overlayRef.hasAttached()) {
      const tooltipRef: ComponentRef<CustomToolTipComponent> = this._overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(CustomToolTipComponent));
      tooltipRef.instance.text = this.text;
      tooltipRef.instance.contentTemplate = this.contentTemplate;
    }    
  }

  /**
   * This method will be called when the mouse goes out of the host element
   * i.e. where this directive is applied
   * This method will close the tooltip by detaching the overlay from the view
   */
  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  hide() {
    this.closeToolTip();
  }

  /**
   * Destroy lifecycle event handler
   * This method will make sure to close the tooltip              
   */
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closeToolTip();
  }

  /**
   * This method will close the tooltip by detaching the component from the overlay
   */
  private closeToolTip() {
    if (this._overlayRef) {
      this._overlayRef.detach();
    }
  }

}
```

declare above component and directives in the respective module.

Now use it the custom tooltip like this -

```
<button mat-raised-button        
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"
        customToolTip [contentTemplate]="template">
  Action
</button>

<ng-template #template>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
     <span>tooltip text</span>
     <span>tootlip description</span>
    </div>
 </ng-template>
```

To show a string similar to MatToolTip, use it like this -

```
<div customToolTip="Showing ToolTip from custom tooltip directive">
 //InnerHtml....
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @user2216584 I am using your custom tooltip. the only thing I have changed is making this custom tooltip works in multiple positions.

```
    const positions = [
      new ConnectionPositionPair(
        { originX: 'start', originY: 'bottom' },
        { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'top' }),
      new ConnectionPositionPair(
        { originX: 'start', originY: 'top' },
        { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'bottom' })];

    const positionStrategy = this._overlayPositionBuilder
      .flexibleConnectedTo(this._elementRef)
      .withPositions(positions);
```

Comment: @SivaBhusarapu Good to know that it’s working for you and good to propose the update to have different positions. I would request you to mark this solution as answered so that it will be helpful for others if they have similar requirements.

Comment: @user2216584 , your solution looks very good I havent tried, any suggetsion on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680815/inserting-a-button-in-every-angular-material-tooltip-and-adding-a-click-function , will this solution of yours would work for my issue

Comment: @Enthu yes, it will work for your requirements as well. The tooltip can render any template. In your requirements you can render button and handle the click. It will work.

Comment: I love this solution, but i am struggling with an *ngFor cycle inside the template. I found that the main problem is on the mouse leave event. Is there any way to emit an event from the component to the directive?

Comment: This is great, but has a few issues. Sometimes the popup doesn't disappear if you move the mouse over it and it also generates a layer for each popup so if you were to use this in a grid you'd get dozens or hundreds of layers generated. Real shame that Material doesn't come with this functionality because it's always way more complicated than you'd think.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `mat-tooltip` of Angular Material does not support to passing a template.

You can check the discussion on GitHub [#5440 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5440#issuecomment-313740211).

But there has an extended Material component to achieve it. Check the examples [mtx-tooltip](https://ng-matero.github.io/extensions/components/tooltip/overview).

```html
<button mat-raised-button [mtxTooltip]="tooltipTpl">
  Action
</button>

<ng-template #tooltipTpl>
  <div>This is a template!</div>
  <div>Ceci est un modèle!</div>
  <div>这是一个模板!</div>
  <div>これはテンプレートです!</div>
  <div class="text-right">هذا قالب!</div>
</ng-template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that using string interpolation inside ngFor.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of itemArray">

      <div class="col-md-1">
        <mat-icon class="mat-18" matTooltip="Edit {{ item.tooltip}}" (click)="callEdit(tab)">edit</mat-icon>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10">
        <span>{{item.name }}</span>
      </div>
          
      <div class="col-md-1">
           <mat-icon class="mat-18"  matTooltip="Delete {{ item.tooltip}}" (click)="callDelete(tab)">delete</mat-icon>
       </div>
          
 </div>
```