# To keep custom tooltip opened until being hovered upon and positioning of the tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Upon hovering the first column of the table , a tooltip appears.
In every material tooltip I want to insert a button at the bottom right after the json data, and upon clicking on this button it should open a angular material dialog.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Alert">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Alert </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <span [matTooltipClass]="{ 'tool-tip': true }" 
           matTooltip="{{(row?.conditionals)?(row.conditionals | json):''}}"> 
       {{row.Alert}}
    </span> 
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

***stackblitz link with Tooltip working***

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-sktlqk?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts

***#EDIT1***
**I have created a custom tooltip , as angular material tooltip was not serving my purpose**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-u5ir3o?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts

**Tooltip is working**

Based on comments I have inserted data and a button in tooltip , but I have 2 things to do:

1) How to keep the tooltip opened until the time user keeps hovering over the tooltip after tooltip is opened so that user can click on the button(now as soon as user leaves the 1st column the tooltip closes)

and

2) Flickering of tooltip occurs as the tooltip opens on top where it is hovered(wanted to place tooltip just at the bottom of the hovered row when first column is hovered upon and if the hovred row is at bottom then tooltip opening just above the hovered row )

Comment: It will become a bit hard to maintain with tooltip, Tooltip is to show information  when user hover's on particular element

Comment: Even if we can achieve this but when you want to click on the button on the tooltip at that we will lose the focus from row and tooltips will just vanish. #JustReThinkOnYourRequirements

Comment: with tooltip it's seems impossible to me for other way it can be done

Comment: first just open dialog box on row click and in that display json and button after that once that button clicked just close the previous dialog box and open new one *use two dialog boxes instead of tooltip and dialog box*

Comment: @Euthu Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-pr1jew

Comment: @Enthu Check this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7zevt-fx1p1p?file=app/tooltip-overview-example.ts

Comment: @user2216584 , it was really helpful , implemented yours solution , needed 1 more help , when I hover on different rows then the previous row hovered tooltip should close and to automatically position the tooltip top when the last bottom row is hovered , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-u5ir3o?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts , I see you have commented out the close function but it would b e great if you can give a subtle way of closing and positioning , thanks

Comment: One recommendation - look into existing tooltip packages, so that you don't have to spend your time finding and fixing problems like this. Tippyjs is very good.

Comment: New to angular, but had a similar problem in pure JS a while ago. I fixed it by having a `div` display after the hover event on a visible element. This `div` then acts as if it were a tooltip and holds your JSON and the button. If I remember correctly it was mainly using the `hover`, `click` events in JS and the `display` options from CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a custom `MatTooltip` and `TooltipComponent`, I wanted to solve the problem with that in mind.

I would at least, at a minimum, extend the `TooltipCompenent` in your `CustomToolTipComponent` as this allows you to leverage existing logic in your directive.

```
export class CustomToolTipComponent extends TooltipComponent
```

I made a lot of changes to your directive and made notes best I could to outline what those changes are doing. Essentially it is following the idea of your own directive while leveraging the extended logic from the extended `TooltipComponent`.

> If I were to write this from scratch, I would explore extending the
>   `MatTooltip` class and not mess with the `CustomToolTipComponent` as
>   there may be a way to accomplish this, while using as much default
>   logic as possible.

This, however, resolves all outstanding action items and gives you enough to go on.

---

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-b2jalw?embed=1&file=app/tool-tip-renderer.directive.ts

Comment: I have an angular material tooltip implemention as well , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-g28f5w?embed=1&file=app/tooltip-overview-example.css

Comment: See revision to stackblitz. Had to handle the state if mouse is in dialog, if listeners are already created don't create additional, and removed logic to see if mouse exited from top. appears to be a more performant/less glitchy approach.

Comment: This indeed works beautifully, thanks , last thing , suppose the last row is near to the bottom of the browser then the tooltip should open above the row instead of at the bottom of the row , please help on this , and this can you please explain , this._toolTipDirectives._results[i].hide('buttonClick');

Comment: This is already built into the spec for the material tooltip. Duplicate the data object in `TooltipOverviewExample` to create enough rows to put one close to the bottom of the browser, and you will see the behavior.

Comment: I did that but tooltip opens in the bottom(overflows in the browser)

Comment: `this._toolTipDirectives._results[i].hide('buttonClick')` there are comments in the HTML that explain how I get the index of the button to close the corresponding tooltip. I am passing a string value as an argument to trigger a different handling of the `_mouseInTooltip` state... as technically the mouse is still in the tooltip, so have to set `_mouseInTooltip = false` to trigger the closing of the tooltip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209781/discussion-between-enthu-and-marshal).

Comment: hi, I have addded a second table, how can I pass the scroll value to the angular tooltip which we had leveraged , so that the tooltip opens above instead of getting hidden in the screen if we have scrolled and there is no space at the bottom of the screen , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-1m1zu8?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts , please suggest, thanks